# Transformation matrix problem with matrix_world, with different results based on the same values in different form

Tags: transforms, matrix

When I created a matrix transformation in the console as follows,
[blender file](http://%20%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5463%22%20/%3E.)

```
>>> c2=bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"].matrix_world
>>> c1=bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world
>>> c1
Matrix(((0.2511853277683258, -0.9679380655288696, 0.0, -47.04343032836914),
    (0.9679380655288696, 0.2511853277683258, 0.0, 18.430648803710938),
    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))

>>> c2
Matrix(((-0.7805679440498352, 0.6250709295272827, 0.0, -10.104384422302246),
    (-0.6250709295272827, -0.7805679440498352, 0.0, 6.641378402709961),
    (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
    (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))

>>> bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = c1*c2
>>> h=c1*c2
>>> bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = h
```

the graphical results of the 3D screen on the active object were different when keep repeating the same line like:

```
>>>bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = c1*c2    
>>>bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = c1*c2
>>>bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = c1*c2
```

The object keeps incrementally moving but another one of the following with a resultant h would't move, like the following:

```
>>>h=c1*c2
>>>bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = h
>>>bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = h
>>>bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = h
```

I wonder it is a bug or something?

Comment: That's strange. I tried it, but don't get that kind of result. Active object moves after the first assignment only, regardless of whether I assign c1 * c2 or h to the matrix_world. Is it possible for you to attach the blend file with the test objects?

Comment: Yes, I can attach the file. Can I attach it to StackExchange?

Comment: You can attach here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Attached as follows: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5463" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5463/). BTW, it looks someone has answered my problem. Anyway, the problem cannot repeat and didn't happen again just like the Schrodinger's Cat!! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around, it seems that the assignment

```
c2 = bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world
```

is not making a deep copy.

Poking into the matrix elements, this kind of result can arise after making the assignment:

```
>>> bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world[0][0] is c2[0][0]
False
```

but....

```
>>> id(bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world[0][0])
2569715751792

>>> id(c2[0][0])
2569715751792
```

.. which seems odd? I'm very much hoping that a more experienced Pythonista will come along and say this is OK.

It certainly seems to be true, after assignment,  that any direct manipulation of the elements of `c2` results in identical changes to the elements of `bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world`, and vice-versa. So, (after the assignment,) an expression like:

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world = c1 * c2
```

is modifying the contents of `c2` as well as `bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world`, explaining the incremental moving.

Comment: Worth mentioning `mw = ob.matrix_world.copy()` to obtain a snapshot on creation would fulfill the expectation  of the questioners code. References like this can also produce segment faults if the matrix is accessed after the object is removed.

Comment: ... oops and meant to add, effectively that last line of code could also be written   `c2 = c1 * c2`

Comment: @batFinger ... which is a much snappier way of answering the OP. So the `copy()` being called by your first comment is  bpy's `ID.copy()`? ... which although it doesn't say so in the docs, must be making a deep copy?.. I guess? Whatever, it will be the safest way to go.

Comment: [copy](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Quaternion.copy)   for some reason `Matrix.copy()` doesn't have the note re removing reference to the original data.  The same applies with any property that is an instance of a  mathutils class  `Vector, Matrix, Color...`

Comment: @Robin Betts Thanks for your suggestion of the deep copy and shallow copy. This may be the keyword to this problem. The result is not definite and make me feel something wrong or imperfect because I tried again the "incremental situation" does not repeat again. Just intuitively remind me of Blender python version's quantum entanglement? :P

Comment: @batFINGER 's is the way to go.

Comment: @PatrickP IMO this is expected behaviour  (To clarify with help from google) _In Python, variables are references to objects and any variable can reference any object. A variable is created by simply using it. That is, variables in Python are dynamic, untyped and are references to objects. ... Each attribute is a reference to another object_  .

Answer (score 4):

[image]
I think the two answers above pretty much explain what's happening. In case of assignments, we need to understand what's being assigned. Is it value or reference to the memory location (in C, it's called pointer)?

When one does an assignment like:

`c1 = bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world`

one essentially stores the reference of matrix_world in c1. So if c1 changes, matrix_world would change and vice versa. Since the active object in this case happens to be (I guess) one of the two cubes, let's say `Cube.001`,  whose matrix world references is held in one of the two references (c2), the assignment to that objects matrix_world with the following line:

`bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world = c1 * c2`

changes the value referenced by matrix_world. But this is also the value referenced by c2. So when the same statement is executed again c2's value is already changed. This should explain the incremental movement. (I missed this point before since I was thinking the active object is not one of Cube.001 and Cube.002 but the original Cube :).

This does not hold true for h, it's a new memory location, which contains the (static) product of the two matrices. This is static in this particular case since none of the operations are manipulating the value referenced by h. So no matter how many times you assign h to the matrix_world the object is not going to change.

Comment: UV for making it clear with pictures :) .. however _I'm_ still confused.. by the results of the Python `is` operator and  `id()` function.  For me, `is` never returns `True`, suggesting references to distinct objects. However `id()` returns identical results at the third level of dereference (to matrix elements) and sometimes to the second level ( `Vector` matrix rows ) and never to the first (the matrices themselves). The result of `id()` can change over time, even with no activity, suggesting that it's derived from memory addresses which are changing due to background memory management?

Comment: Thanks for the UV :) I shall attempt to summarize my understanding (open to corrections) : Let's say the actual 4 X 4 matrix is at location `xx` in memory. `obj.matrix_world` is at location `yy` and it refers (or points) to `xx`. With the assignment `c = obj.matrix_world`, we aallocate a new memory space `zz`, stored in c but pointing to `xx`. So `xx` can be changed through `c` or `matrix_world`. But the "actual values" of `c` and `matrix_world` are `zz` and `yy` respectively (the two `id()` values). So `c is obj.matrix_world` won't be `True` whereas `c == obj.matrix_world` will.

Comment: @RobinBetts http://scottlobdell.me/2013/08/understanding-python-variables-as-pointers/

Comment: Thanks! .. My understanding of your understanding :) is that there's _another_ layer of indirection above the ones I've been assuming in my answer...this conversation really would need pictures.. I'll wait for experience to teach me a bit more. All this Python is pointing to C++ classes, anyway? Whatever..when in doubt, @batFINGER's `copy()` recommendation seems good.

Answer (score 1):

when you use structs like a matrix resulting from `h=c1*c2` the value of this multiplication would be stored in `h` but when you use `c1*c2` equivalently you are assigning this:

```
bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world=bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world *
                                       bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"].matrix_world
```

so you will get different results if the active object be one one of these two cubes.

but if you use the value of this multiplication this will never change:

```
c1 = bpy.data.objects["Cube.002"].matrix_world
c2 = bpy.data.objects["Cube.001"].matrix_world

h=c1*c2

bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world=h
```

because now `h` is a simple struct